# How to resolve "PLACES_API_ACCESS_NOT_CONFIGURED"

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

Friends, I was getting this error while implementing google map API in my APP.  I was getting this issue:

> Error getting autocomplete prediction API call:
>   Status{statusCode=PLACES_API_ACCESS_NOT_CONFIGURED, resolution=null}

While searching result for these issues, I got a solution that "open google play console and enable Google Place SDK for Android". But while opening GOOGLE PLAY SDK FOR ANDROID ,I was unable to open it and got these issues as shown in figure below. Now I able to resole this issues.See my answer given below in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54965020/apiexception-9003-places-api-access-not-configured/54969500#54969500) to implement new SDk released. Thanks.

[image: Error While Enabling Google Place SDK For Android.]

Comment: This is deprected now. I am able to resolve this problem.

Comment: I successfully resolve this issue.By using this migration guide https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/client-migration

Comment: I removed `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:16.0.0'` and added `implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places-compat:1.0.0'`. Did the gradle sync. I don't have any "Powered by Google" assets. So, I did not change anything for that. My minSdkVersion is 23 (which is above 14). 

After following all these steps, I am still getting the error. Could you please tell me how did you resolve the error. It would be of great help to me. Thanks!

Comment: @harshpamnani have you studied the migration guide and implemented it in your new code?

Comment: Yes I tried. But it doesn't seem to work. What all steps we need to follow from that guide?

Comment: @harshpamnani Actually I have implemented  new place library  for AutoComplete Place   from this documentation. Give some time and try, you will surely implement in your project by following step by step given in that. If you can't ,I will share you code of AutoComplete Place(If problem in implementing AutoComplete ).  Thanks.....

Comment: Thanks Rahul. I will try today and let you know.

Comment: Or else I will send my code. Can you please just have a look at it once and see what am I doing wrong.

Comment: I am still not able to do it. Can you please share your email address? I will send my codes. Can you please check what is my error.

Comment: @harshpamnani My email Address is rahulkushwaha482@gmail.com

Comment: I have sent you a detailed email. Could you please check. Thanks!

Comment: ok @harshpamnani I have seen and I will send you feedbacks.Thanks..

Comment: Thanks Rahul. It's working now. Anyways Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hi Friends I have successfully resolve this issue.I was implementing Auto Complete Goole places in my app. This was provided by Google play services. Now the main issue is that Place SDK for Android is deprecated from Google play services on 29 Jan.Now,A new SDK is released instead of. Place sdk for Android. Now you can use this migration guide to implement place sdk in your project. Link is available here.

[Place SDK for Android migration guide.](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/client-migration)

Also see the step by step guide how to implement AutoComplete in your project  .Look here this link[step by step guide to implement  Autocomplete in our app.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54965020/apiexception-9003-places-api-access-not-configured/54969500#54969500)

Hope this will help you.Thanks.....

Comment: Is this the solution?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky ,Yes after using Migration guide and implementing in my project .I have written these steps.Hope you will better understand from Migration Guide.

Answer (score 1):

Please check if you have created the project from old site-
https://code.google.com/apis/console/?noredirect

You need to enable the service from there.

Comment: Hello Shivam Yadav.Perhaps you haven't know yet that Place SDK for Android is deprecated now.So that the given issues occurs . Now I have implemented new Place API in my project and is successful working.