# " Status{statusCode=PLACES_API_ACCESS_NOT_CONFIGURED, resolution=null}"

Tags: android

I am getting this error on my Android Phone when I try to type in an input on the `PlaceAutoCompleteTextView`:

`"Status{statusCode=PLACES_API_ACCESS_NOT_CONFIGURED, resolution=null}"`

I have done this

- Go to console.developers.google.com
- Select your project associated with the Google API Key
- Enable google places API for android

Still it is still displaying that error.

Comment: Hi Wisdom I have already posted this questions and its answer in this link Check it.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54551166/how-to-resolve-places-api-access-not-configured

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resolve "PLACES\_API\_ACCESS\_NOT\_CONFIGURED"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54551166/how-to-resolve-places-api-access-not-configured)

Comment: I have given step by step solutions of this.Hop this will help you.Thanks..

Comment: @RahulKushwaha, i have followed this steps but when i build my project on my android phone it worked fine, but immediately i tried to put in a text in the text box it will display the same error   “ Status{statusCode=PLACES_API_ACCESS_NOT_CONFIGURED, resolution=null}”
On my android phone

Comment: ok,generate a new api key and try.

Comment: It means you say that while searching any place ,autocomplete listner is not working .Or,Click on any  place it gives such an error?

Comment: OK I think while clicking on any place you want to take that place and show on any TextView,right?On that time you got that error.

Comment: I think you forget to enable all apis related to places in console.developers.google.com

Comment: Be sure to Enables these apis      Time Zone API,Geolocation API,geocoading,plase api,plase sdk for android,and others too.

Comment: You check from this link. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/

Comment: @RahulKushwaha i have tried all this but am still getting that error, is there any upgrade on the android APIs.

Comment: OK,i Think you should create new project on Google Play console .do the same steps as you follows previous.Thanks.....I faced same issues and then I had created new project and get new api key . I resolved it successfully.Hope it will works...

Comment: @RahulKushwaha i want to  Update  "Powered by Google" assets: how do i do that

Comment: I can't understand you."Powered By Google assets".Will you please explain in details.